# How to search tracks by their title with the Sound Cloud API?

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I even not sure if it's possible. I've checked the documentation [here](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks) and [here](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript) but it's not very clear to me. When I was searching tracks manually, I noticed that browser send this request to

```
https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/search?q=ramdeni%20malodine&qid=fc199042a5efd2b2&facet=model&user_id=787638-587135-803806-46602&limit=10&offset=0&linked_partitioning=1
```

and get response that I want. But again I'm not sure I can do that via API.

Comment: Why close? Have you ever read their API my dear author of close? It isn't clear at all

Comment: Well your question(s) isn't(aren't) clear at all. As someone with 1.2k, you should know that questions posts must contain exactly one question, and show a minimal effort in doing that. There is no documentation at all? Or is it simply very bad? If there is any, what have you tried? What difficulties are you finding?

Comment: @Kroltan updated. Is that sufficient?

Comment: Yes, much better. I may answer this in 5 minutes or so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing a Ctrl+F in page and finding for "search", I found a [relevant link](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#search).

You can conduct searches by using filters, one of them being the `q` filter, which is a search query:

```js
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
});
// find all sounds of buskers licensed under 'creative commons share alike'
SC.get('/tracks', {
    q: 'streetlights',
    license: 'cc-by-sa'
}, function(tracks) {
  console.log(tracks);
});
```

*(example provided from the link above)*

You can also use many other filters, all of those listed in [the Tracks docs](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks), to the very bottom, in a table called "filters".

While the formatting isn't the best, their API is quite very well documented, IMO.

Comment: so easy! Ok, I take back my words about SC API. Thanks!

Comment: @V_B I agree with you that it's very unreadable, they use spacing in a inconsistent manner, and the fact that all sections are stitched together makes a lot of confused scrolling, but that's more of a styling issue than actual problems with functionality, in my opinion.